# How to seamlessly proxy (locally) to a proxy (to the out side)

Tags: proxy

I am a developer working inside a corporate network. I have a Virtual Machine, which I use a login (with some elevated privileges) on a different domain than the one I use for logging onto my physical machine. However to access the internet from inside my VM I have to set the IE proxy settings to use my regular login credentials.

This means that many of the application I use have flaky , no access, or keep require me to enter my credentials to access. (I haven't worked out the pattern of when or why)

**I am wondering can I setup a local proxy (similar to how fiddler does to intercept traffic) that will know the proxy credentials to get out to the internet, but not require authentication for local apps?**

Note this is on windows, using AD etc.
Also some of the applications are running as a service under a service account.